# Finding all non-zero values in a table/row

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

Been searching for awhile and decided to throw this out there to see if anyone could provide a good direction for this. My table has ~100 (and expanding) rows by about 24 columns and looks something like:

```
ID  yr1 yr2 yr3 yr4

id1  $-      $-      $35     $-   
id2  $40     $45     $-      $-   
id3  $35     $-      $30     $37
```

I want to ignore all zero values and create a representation of this table that looks like this (I don't care about the column headings):

```
ID          
id1  $35        
id2  $40     $45    
id3  $35     $30     $37
```

Seems like there should be a simple(ish) solution, but I haven't figured it out yet. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've been working on this for an hour, but can't make it work without VBA.  Good Luck.

Comment: Having mis-intepreted your "ignore all zeroes" I agree with Lance. I think this would be fiendishly difficult with formula - are you ok with vba?

Comment: VBA solution added. New table goes to a new sheet, the code uses arrays and deliberate errors in place of zeroes for efficiency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Update: Removed initial suggestion and replaced with VBA solution]**

```
Sub ReArrange()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim X
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngCol As Long
X = [a1].CurrentRegion
For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
    For lngCol = 1 To UBound(X, 2)
        If X(lngRow, lngCol) = 0 Then X(lngRow, lngCol) = "=1/0"
    Next
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws = Sheets.Add
ws.[a1].Resize(UBound(X, 1), UBound(X, 2)) = X
On Error Resume Next
ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16).Delete xlToLeft
On Error GoTo 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Problem with #2 is that I want excel to find and replace with the first non-zero item in the row, I don't want to just hide the zeroes. i.e. if(a1=0, check a2, a3, a4, etc.